# Is there a html tag to display the value of an enum

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, enums, tag-helpers

Display value of enum in html in ASP.NET MVC.

I have the following: in C#, the following code will produce the lookup value = "Low".

```
enum ERisk { NA = 0, Low = 1, Medium = 2, High = 3 } (Class=Tasks)
var rval=Enum.GetName(typeof(Tasks.ERisk), 1);
```

Is there a `@html` tag to display the lookup value of the enum in the html output?

The following does not work. "item.Risk=1" and I want to display the text "Low" as per the above enum ERisk

```
 <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Enum.GetName(typeof(Tasks.ERisk), item.Risk));

    @model IEnumerable<Tasks>
       ...
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        // The following does not work. item.Risk=1 and I want to display the text "Low" as per the above enum ERisk
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Enum.GetName(typeof(Tasks.ERisk), item.Risk));
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>Enum.GetName(typeof(Tasks.ERisk), item.Risk));
        </td>
    }
</td>
```

Comment: Why not just `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Risk)`? Or even `@item.Risk`?

Comment: As per above @item.Risk=1 and I want to display the lookup value of 1 which is "Low" as per the enum.

Answer (score 0):

use an ordered list to retrieve enumeration values using html tags.

View:

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3

Code:

```
<ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: i dont want to display the whole list, item.Risk stores the numerical value and i want to display the name value based on the enum so e.g. item.Risk might equal 1 then display "Low" as per enum.